# Cannot change TEdit Text in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am adding components to a form at run time and I am also adding events that change properties of these components in a dictionary to call them later.

```
TEventBeforeInsert = function(var AComponent: TComponent; AForm: TForm): Boolean of Object;

TFieldBase = class
private
  FEvent:TEventBeforeInsert;
....
function TFieldBase.EventBeforeInsert: TEventBeforeInsert;
begin
  Result:=FEvent;
end;

function TFieldBase.EventBeforeInsert(AEvent: TEventBeforeInsert): TFieldBase ;
begin
  FEvent:=AEvent;
  Result:=Self;
end;

....
```

The Form Call

```
TFormBase.New
.addStringField
(
    TFieldBase.New
    .Enabled(True)
    .Description('User')
    .EventBeforeInsert(TEvents.New.EditFillUser), TTabsNames.Tab1
).Show();
```

The Form Class

```
TFormBase = class(TForm)
private
FDictionary: TDictionary<String, TEventBeforeInsert>;
...
function TFormBase.addStringField(AField: TFieldBase; ATab: TTabsNames): TFormBase;
var
  FLink: TLinkControlToField;
  FEdit: TEdit;
begin
  Result := Self;
  FEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.Visible := True;
  FEdit.Parent := TPanel(PanelParent.FindComponent('PanelTab' + Ord(ATab).ToString));
  FEdit.Enabled:=AField.Enabled;

 
  if Assigned(AField.EventBeforeInsert) then
  begin
    FDictionary.Add(FEdit.Name,AField.EventBeforeInsert);
  end;
end;
...
procedure TFormBase.rectInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    Item:String;
begin
  for Item in FDictionary.Keys do
  begin
    if Not FDictionary.Items[Item](Self.FindComponent(Item),Self) then
      Exit;
  end;
end;
```

I'm having a problem here, when debugging I see the text property being changed correctly, but no changes are made to the form being displayed.

```
TEvents = class
...
function TEvents.EditFillUser(AComponent: TComponent;AForm: TForm): Boolean;
begin
  TEdit(AComponent).Text:=IntToStr(0);
  Result:=True;
end
```

I'm thinking it may be a problem that the variable is being passed by value ... Can someone help me?

Edit 1:
I've tried with the dictionary declared like this:

```
FDictionary: TDictionary<TComponent, TEventBeforeInsert>;
...
if Not FDictionary.Items[Item](Item,Self) then //call
```

And I also tried use TForm reference like this:

```
function TEvents.EditFillUser(AComponent: String;AForm: TForm): Boolean;
begin
  TEdit(AForm.FindComponent(AComponent)).Text:=IntToStr(0);
  Result:=True;
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `TFormBase.addStringField()`, you are not assigning a `Name` value to the newly create `TEdit` object before inserting it into `FDictionary.`. Only components created at design-time have auto-generated `Name`s.  Components created at run-time do not.  So, you are tracking your objects using blank `Name`s.  If you want to track the objects by `Name`, you need to actually assign your own value to `FEdit.Name`, eg:

```pascal
function TFormBase.addStringField(AField: TFieldBase; ATab: TTabsNames): TFormBase;
var
  ...
  FEdit: TEdit;
  FEvent: TEventBeforeInsert;
begin
  ...
  FEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  FEdit.Name := 'SomeUniqueNameHere'; // <-- for you to decide on...
  ...
 
  FEvent := AField.EventBeforeInsert;
  if Assigned(FEvent) then
    FDictionary.Add(FEdit.Name, FEvent);
end;
```

However, in this particular case, I see no reason to use a `TDictionary` at all.  Consider using a `TList` instead, then you don't need the `Name`s at all.  This will also boost the performance of the iteration in `TFormBase.rectInsertClick()` since it won't have to hunt for every `TComponent` object using `FindComponent()` anymore:

```pascal
TFormBase = class(TForm)
private
  type TEventBeforeInsertPair = TPair<TComponent, TEventBeforeInsert>;
  FBeforeInsertEvents: TList<TEventBeforeInsertPair>;
  ...
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;
  ...
end;

...

constructor TFormBase.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FBeforeInsertEvents := TList<TEventBeforeInsertPair>.Create;
end;

destructor TFormBase.Destroy;
begin
  FBeforeInsertEvents.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TFormBase.addStringField(AField: TFieldBase; ATab: TTabsNames): TFormBase;
var
  ...
  FEdit: TEdit;
  FEvent: TEventBeforeInsert;
begin
  ...
  FEdit := TEdit.Create(Self);
  ...

  FEvent := AField.EventBeforeInsert;
  if Assigned(FEvent) then
    FBeforeInsertEvents.Add(TEventBeforeInsertPair.Create(FEdit, FEvent));
end;

procedure TFormBase.rectInsertClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Item: TEventBeforeInsertPair;
begin
  for Item in FBeforeInsertEvents do
  begin
    if not Item.Value(Item.Key, Self) then
      Exit;
  end;
end;

...
```

Also, your `TEvents.EditFillUser()` method does not match the definition of `TEventBeforeInsert`.  The 1st parameter of `TEventBeforeInsert` is declared as passing the `TComponent` pointer by `var` reference (why?), but the 1st parameter of `EditFillUser()` is not doing that.  Unless you want your event handlers to alter what the `TComponent` pointers are pointing at (which won't work the way you are currently using `TEventBeforeInsert` with `TDictionary`), then there is no reason to pass around the `TComponent` pointers by `var` reference at all:

```pascal
TEventBeforeInsert = function(AComponent: TComponent; AForm: TForm): Boolean of Object;
```

Also, your use of `TEvents.New` appears to be a memory leak, as nobody is taking ownership of the newly created `TEvents` object (unless its constructor is adding the object to some internal list that we can't see).  Same with `TFieldBase.New`.  And even `TFormBase.New` (assuming there is no `OnClose` event that sets `Action=caFree` when the Form is closed).  At some point, you need to call `Free()` any `class` object that you `Create()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
Sorry I couldn't put the whole code because it would be too long. 
Yes, right at the beginning I had a problem with the name of the component so I started to name it as follows:
`FEdit.Name:='Edit '+ FComponentCounter`;
The var in the definition of EditFillUser was one of many tests. And I forgot to change to make the question, but I already edited it. 

The leak does not occur, because I am using interfaces with static class methods . As I said I put it that way to simplify my question.
At last the I discovered a navigator cleaning up my TEdit 